# Using type hints in Clojure for Java return values

Tags: java, clojure, type-hinting

I'm working on some Java / Clojure interoperability and came across a reflection warning for the following code:

```
(defn load-image [resource-name]
  (javax.imageio.ImageIO/read 
    (.getResource 
      (class javax.imageio.ImageIO) 
      resource-name)))

=> Reflection warning, clojure/repl.clj:37 - reference to field read can't be resolved.
```

I'm surprised at this because getResource always returns a URL and I would therefore expect the compiler to use the appropriate static method in javax.imageio.ImageIO/read.

The code works fine BTW so it is clearly finding the right method at run time.

So two questions:

1. Why is this returning a reflection warning?
2. What type hint do I need to fix this?

Comment: I get no reflection warnings with this code. Could you provide more details on your setup? (Clojure version -- though I tried both 1.1 and bleeding edge -- and the JVM version at least.)

Comment: I'm using a mid-May build of Clojure 1.2 and the Java 1.6 JDK. Maybe I should try the latest 1.2 build?

Comment: Sun JDK or OpenJDK? As for the build, sure, give it a shot, though it works for me both with my own local build and the 1.1 release.

Comment: Sun JDK - but as per Peter's answer below it appears to be an issue in the REPL code rather than the code above. So hopefully that one is already fixed for the latest 1.2

Comment: Is this really doing the right thing? (class javax.imageio.ImageIO) is Class. If you want the class ImageIO just use it directly: (.getResource javax.imageio.ImageIO resource-name).

Comment: Thanks kotarak - your version also works and is neater!

Comment: mikera: I have actually tested this with a bunch of 1.2 builds and still couldn't reproduce it. See also my comment on Peter's answer. By the way, have you got around to trying a newer build? If yes, I'd love to know the commit number (or date, or anything useful to identify it exactly) of the build you were originally using. I'm genuinely curious about this.

Comment: Hi Michal I'm running the 1.2.0-master-20100507.230258 build. Pretty sure the warning is in the repl.clj code rather than my code but haven't yet figured out what I am doing to trigger it..... p.s. I'm also running within Eclipse if you think that could be making a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAICS has this nothing to do with your code or compilation. It is part of the source-fn function of the REPL :

```
 ...
      (let [text (StringBuilder.)
            pbr (proxy [PushbackReader] [rdr]
                  (read [] (let [i (proxy-super read)]
                             (.append text (char i))
                             i)))]
 ...
```

and used to display source code in the REPL shell, AFAICT.

Comment: Very good spot! Guess this is warning for the Clojure development team to fix up then?

Comment: Reflection warnings are emitted at compile time. By the time anything can be typed into the REPL, the REPL code is of course done compiling. In fact, stuff in `clojure.jar` is compiled ahead-of-time, so I can't see how any reflection warnings connected to it would ever appear at the REPL. Moreover, I still can't reproduce this issue, and I've tried a current Hudson snapshot, two local 1.2 builds and the 1.1 release jar. Just trying to bring some constructive rain to the parade so as to help wash away any remaining obstacles to our understanding of this...

Comment: The line it appears to be complaining about in repl.clj is: (proxy [PushbackReader] [rdr] (read [] (let [i (proxy-super read)] (.append text (char i)) i))) - interestingly I note that the warning goes away if I put (:use [clojure.repl]) in the ns declaration before the (set! *warn-on-reflection* true) line so maybe what is happening is that this changes the timing of the compilation?

Answer (score 2):

For others who find this post (as I did) when wondering why they get reflection warnings when using `proxy-super`...

Every proxy method has an implicit `this` first arg, which, alas, is not type-hinted (presumably because there are a number of possible types being implemented by the proxy and the resultant proxy class is created later).

So, if you ever call methods on `this` from inside the proxy (which is what `proxy-super` ends up doing), then you'll see reflection warnings.

The simple solution is to just wrap your code in a `let` that uses type-hinting.  E.g.:

```
(let [^SomeClass this this]
  (proxy-super foo)
  (.bar this))
```